# The Bunyan log is not sent before process.exit

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

Today I ran into a problem in the `@google-cloud/logging-bunyan` extension for `bunyan`. The problem is that it is not able to send the log when there is an exit right after.

Example:

```js
logger.fatal({
  [LOGGING_TRACE_KEY]: e.stack
}, e.message)
process.exit(1)
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score -1):

Please check if your plugin was properly installed.
I have found the following guide, [Using Bunyan](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_bunyan) that may help you with your issue.

You will find this example at the end of this page:

```
'use strict';

// [START logging_bunyan_quickstart]
const bunyan = require('bunyan');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library for Bunyan
const {LoggingBunyan} = require('@google-cloud/logging-bunyan');

// Creates a Bunyan Stackdriver Logging client
const loggingBunyan = new LoggingBunyan();

// Create a Bunyan logger that streams to Stackdriver Logging
// Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/bunyan_log"
const logger = bunyan.createLogger({
  // The JSON payload of the log as it appears in Stackdriver Logging
  // will contain "name": "my-service"
  name: 'my-service',
  streams: [
    // Log to the console at 'info' and above
    {stream: process.stdout, level: 'info'},
    // And log to Stackdriver Logging, logging at 'info' and above
    loggingBunyan.stream('info'),
  ],
});

// Writes some log entries
logger.error('warp nacelles offline');
logger.info('shields at 99%');
// [END logging_bunyan_quickstart]
```

Also, please check this [link](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-logging-bunyan/blob/master/samples/quickstart.js) as reference.

On the other hand, I recommend you to review the following guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in order to provide a better context on what you are doing and what you want to achieve.